# How to Tie UITextFields to different variables to use in an equation in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, uitextfield

I am just starting to learn how to program, and am trying to make an app that allows a user to input numbers into a text field, and then have them stored to variables that I can plug into an equation and have the result printed as a graph. I have been looking around on the internet for examples of similar stuff, but I can find anything too similar. It makes me think I am not searching for the right topics, and I'm feeling a little overwhelmed. Could someone point me in the right direction or maybe explain the best way to make an app like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `UITextField` is a subclass of `UIControl` and as such you can set an action on events. Here you are looking for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event.

This should lead you to what you need to use the text inputed in your textfields.

Edit: You'll find some references [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) and [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to tie the contents of a `UITextField` to a variable (that I know of). The common strategy is to listen for when the user has edited the contents of the text view.

You'll want to start by looking at the `UITextFieldDelegate` [protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) in particular the events  `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` are where you'll want to start.

If you only care about when the user is done entering data then you'll only need to look at `textViewDidEndEditing:` and get the text view's contents then.

Some other functions that you'll likely want to read up on are `NSString`'s `floatValue`, `integerValue` and related methods, as well as `UITextViewDelegate`'s `shouldReturn:`.  The `NSString` methods are easy ways to get the number from the textview's text and `textFieldShouldReturn:`